# Mount exited with exit code 13

Tags: mount, ntfs, external-hdd, gpt

I have a 1TB external hard drive that I recently formatted to NTFS. It was mounting on my Ubuntu 11.10 fine until just now. I didn't make any changes to affect my OS or my exhdd.

The error that I get is:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

I did read [**this**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19069/error-mounting-mount-exited-with-exit-code-13) and [**this**](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-corrupted-windows-ntfs-filesystem-ubuntu/). But neither helped.

I tried installing `ntfsfix` but no such package exists anymore.
I have never used this HDD on a windows machine. If I need to use an other machine to do stuff to fix this, I have access to a mac.

Any advice?

This is my sudo fdisk -l output:
What in the world is GPT? I didn't do that. It used to be NTFS.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000586fb

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2148   961320312   480659082+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2       961320313   976773167     7726427+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5       961320314   976773167     7726427   83  Linux

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xcfd88605

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GPT is the [GUID Partition Table,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) which is the next-generation partitioning system used on Macs, UEFI-based PCs, and disks over 2TiB in size. It can also be used on smaller disks even on BIOS-based systems, so long as you don't expect to boot Windows from such disks. As the `fdisk` warning message notes, `fdisk` doesn't support GPT, so you shouldn't attempt to use `fdisk` on this disk. Instead, use `gdisk` (part of the `gdisk` or `gptfdisk` package, depending on how you install it) or `parted`.

GPT doesn't have anything to do with your problem, though. The mount error message indicates an I/O error, which most probably indicates a hardware fault. You might try running a SMART test on the disk using a tool like `gsmartcontrol` (GUI) or `smartctl` (text-mode). This should turn up any hardware fault, but the output of a SMART test can be hard to interpret. Since you say it's an external drive, it could also be a loose or damaged cable, so you might try reseating or replacing it. Cable faults won't turn up in a SMART test.

More generally, if it's not actually a hardware fault, you *cannot* do adequate filesystem tests on NTFS from either Linux or OS X; *only* Windows provides tools to do this. You may not be able to mount an NTFS disk that needs filesystem checks, so you *must* be able to get an NTFS disk to a Windows system from time to time to deal with such problems. If you never use the disk on a Windows system, NTFS is the wrong filesystem to use on it.

For Linux-only use, it's best to use a Linux-native filesystem, such as ext2fs, ext3fs, ext4fs, ReiserFS, XFS, JFS, or perhaps Btrfs. (I wouldn't use ext2fs on a 1TB disk, though.) If you use the disk for both Linux and OS X, I'd use either FAT or HFS+. Despite its age, FAT is still the best-supported cross-OS filesystem. It has problems with a maximum file size of 4GiB, though, which can be a problem if you store multimedia or other big files. HFS+ is OK for Linux/OS X use, provided you understand how to disable the journal and deal with permissions issues. (If the journal is enabled, Linux won't write to HFS+ unless you use an override mount option, which may reduce safety.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, since I plan on using the hard drive across Linux/OsX/Win7, I chose an NTFS system. The hard drive isn't journaled. There were issues with write access on the hard drive. I had to format it again (into NTFS) and `chown` all the folders in it. That has worked so far.

Answer (score 41):

This really worked for me.

On some recent Linux releases, you need to install ntfs-3g utilities. Try `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` or download from http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/. ntfs-3g includes ntfsprogs.

```
ntfsprogs is a suite of NTFS utilities based around a shared library. The tools are available for free and come with full source code.

mkntfs: Create an NTFS volume on a partition
ntfscat: Print a file on the standard output
ntfsclone: Efficiently backup/restore a volume at the sector level
ntfscluster: Given a cluster, or sector, find the file
ntfsfix: Forces Windows to check NTFS at boot time
ntfsinfo: Dump a file’s attributes, completely
ntfslabel: Display or set a volume’s label
ntfslib: Move all the common code into a shared library
ntfsls: List directory contents
ntfsresize: Resize an NTFS volume
ntfsundelete: Find files that have been deleted and recover them
ntfswipe: Write zeros over the unused parts of the disk
ntfsdefrag: Defragment files, directories and the MFT
ntfsck: Perform consistancy checks on a volume
nttools: Command-line tools to view/change an offline NTFS volume, e.g. ntfscp, ntfsgrep, ntfstouch, ntfsrm, ntfsrmdir, ntfsmkdir
ntfsdiskedit: Walk the tree of NTFS ondisk structures (and alter them)

Be careful with these utilities, they might damage the filesystem, or your hard disk !
```

(Source: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ntfsprogs.htm)

With ntfs-3g installed (`sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`) you should execute the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/partitionName
```

After this command you should expect the following output:

```
~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb3
Mounting volume... FAILED
Attempting to correct errors...
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... FAILED
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 0...OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdb3 was processed successfully.
```

After this step you should be able to access your external drive partition as usual, mount or use nautilus to access your files.

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: you should note that it has to be the actual partition name, rather than the device. So `/dev/sdb1`, not just `/dev/sdb`

Comment: this does work..

Comment: most simple solution.... why this error occurs?