# Unable to mount NTFS external hard drive

Tags: mount, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I am having trouble mounting my external hard drive, every time I try and do so I get the following message:

```
"Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/fuzzy27/My Book: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/fuzzy27/My Book"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details."
```

How do I go about or what do I need to do in order to fix this error/problem without losing any of the data on my hard drive?

Is there no other way of fixing it without having to reinstall windows or finding someone using windows?

Comment: see the message: "NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot into Windows twice." Windows problems you fix with windows tools.

Comment: yeah I think you have to shut down restart windows and then come to ubuntu to access it. Is the drive encrypted or something?

Comment: As the message says: "run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot into Windows twice." This means you have to boot Windows or take the drive to a friend who has a computer running Windows. Then use the Windows Command Line and enter the command "chkdsk /f X: where X is the external drive. Then as the message says, reboot into Windows twice.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. You need to run `chkdsk /f` on a windows environment or use **HirensBootCD** booted into a USB. I've been through the same and it helped me to fix.

Comment: Related Question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/183970/mount-exited-with-exit-code-13

Comment: For other users, you might have to turn off fastboot: https://sudopacman.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/dont-use-ntfsfix-in-linux-just-turn-off-fast-boot-in-windows/

Answer (score 113):

Install ntfs-3g with `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`.
Then run the ntfsfix command on your NTFS partition.

> ntfsfix v2.0.0 (libntfs 10:0:0)
>
> Usage: ntfsfix [options] device
>
> ```
> Attempt to fix an NTFS partition.
>
> -h, --help             Display this help
> -V, --version          Display version information
> ```
>
> For example: ntfsfix /dev/hda6
>
> Developers' email address:
>   linux-ntfs-dev@lists.sf.net Linux NTFS
>   homepage: http://www.linux-ntfs.org

**Note**: Whenever you're dealing with partition, make sure that you have a complete backup just to be on the safe side.

---

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

Then run it:

```
sudo testdisk
```

and follow the instructions. You must search for partitions and then write the changes.

Thanks to answerers here:

- [Fix corrupt NTFS partition without Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47700/fix-corrupt-ntfs-partition-without-windows)
- [Repair NTFS without Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330733/repair-ntfs-without-windows)

Comment: Getting rid of the middle section of yr answer is recommended.  As you remarked `ntfsprogs` is long gone. The remainder of yr answer stands.

Comment: FYI, if you've used ddrescue to pull an image off of a dying harddrive you can use ntfsfix on the image to address NTFS issues too. Just point ntfsfix at the image file (ntfsfix dyinghdd.image) instead of the actual device in /dev/.

Comment: The point here is that the hard drive is not being mounted correctly. How then can a backup be performed?

Comment: First line of this answer was sufficient in my case.

Comment: sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdc1 fixed my issue and was able to mount the external Hard Disk.

Comment: For Centos7, install the ntfsprogs package to get ntfsfix (not included with the ntfs-3g package)

Answer (score 92):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/298729/how-to-fix-a-damaged-corrupted-ntfs-filesystem-partition-without-losing-the-data/298741#298741) was good enough for me:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

On **Ubuntu 14.04** this comes with:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

---

*Older versions of Ubuntu (e.g. 12.04) would require:*

```
sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs
```

Comment: Just note that this may not recover all corrupted files the way a Windows `chkdsk /F` would so if you have a Windows machine that should be tried first.

Comment: actually i have tried that with windows. what now happens is, it mounts in windows but data transfer is really slow (0 to 70 to 200 kbps). As for ubuntu, it does not mount at all. the same problem. so i now ran this ntfsfix. it made all corrections. after "ntfs partition /dev/sdb1 was processed successfully" it is now mounting. :). but the problem is speed. still 200 kbps

Comment: Sounds like physical damage. If I were you I'd buy a drive duplicator to do a low level copy of all bits, and throw that drive away before it causes you to lose more precious data. https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B003WV5DLA?pc_redir=T1

Comment: @sridhar Thannks it worked

Comment: This worked as a charm nevertheless I have to do the same command at EACH reboot of my system...

Comment: @c24b maybe your shutdown process is always interrupting something writing to the disk (no easy solution to this), or maybe ubuntu is just being stupid (I've seen that before but don't have an idea how to solve it)

Comment: WORKED PERFECTLY :)

Comment: The volume now mounts correctly. Thank you! (in my case the external drive was /dev/sda1, so people remember to run a lsblk to confirm which is the right device. I guess for most folks running laptops with nvme interfaces since the last 3 years or so it must be the case).

Comment: You made my day. Thanks.

Comment: This worked like charm for me

Comment: Legendary status! Worked on ubuntu 20.

Comment: Hello from 2023. This worked like a charmed, in 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks this saves my time. (-:

Comment: I don't have any windows installed ! but this error happened after power break, this solution work for me ! thanks .

Answer (score 3):

This looks like an old question, but I ran into this issue in ubuntu 15.10. I mounted the hard drive in windows and simply removed the ._.Trashes directory on the drive that happened to contain a lot of data. Then I plugged it back into linux and it worked fine.

Comment: Hello from 2017! Mine is even weirder: I just plugged my disk into a different USB port..? No idea why the error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this happens to anyone else and they don't hit [dr Hannibal Lecter's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500647/unable-to-mount-ntfs-external-hard-drive#comment1420941_707866), I just had to try a different USB port.  There's nothing wrong with that USB port, but for some reason, it wouldn't work with this drive.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the external hard disk to a windows pc.

When the disk enumerates, run `chkdsk /f [driveletter]:` from Command Prompt.

When I tried ntfs-3g, it suggested in terminal to run `chkdsk`. :)
(I am on Ubuntu 14.04, real native install, not on any virtualized env)

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the device in the FAT format using the ubuntu utility **Disks** solved the problem for me