# Can't access my disk

Tags: 14.04, ntfs, disk

I have a problem .I can't access to my disk
see the message below :

```
Error mounting /dev/sda7 at /media/marwen/SEHLI: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda7" "/media/marwen/SEHLI"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda7': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/500647/unable-to-mount-ntfs-external-hard-drive

Comment: I did this but my problem didn't solved

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74105/how-do-you-repair-an-input-output-error-in-an-ntfs-partition

Comment: If chkdsk goes well check the property of your disk file system for NTFS. Also check whether the particular volume labelled as RAID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all, this solved my problem:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda7
```