# I can't copy files into my pen drive

Tags: 14.04

Pen Drive detecting OK and also show all data proper but I can't copy any folder or file into pen drive form the system

Please suggest what i do

Comment: edit you question, and show us the errors you get when you try to copy files. Also perform `df -h` and provide the output as part of your question

Comment: If the pendrive is good, you should unmount it and mount it according to the following link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/886701/how-do-i-get-permission-to-edit-in-my-usb/886735#886735 . Otherwise, please check if you can write to the pendrive in another computer and with another operating system. If there are still problems, please come back, and we can try other ways.