# can't mount 1TB NTFS drive

Tags: usb-drive, ntfs

why is this happening? ntfs drive.
[image]

edit: I did NOT hibernate my Windows and fast startup is off. also this is a USB disk not a HARD DRIVE

Comment: this is a USB disk guys

Comment: In that case, see here. It's pretty much the same answer though, use ntfsfix: http://askubuntu.com/questions/500647/unable-to-mount-ntfs-external-hard-drive

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/501035/665251

Comment: Look at the system log (usually /var/log/syslog) and dmesg right after that error comes up - what do they say? If it's input/output errors that points to bad hardware, or at least bad USB connections.

Comment: @mchid that answered my question! please make an answer with that information and i will accept/upvote. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `ntfs-3g` package, by running

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

and then run

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/[DRIVE_NAME]
```

Example:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: great job @Ruhul :)